# Turn on autocompletion in macros

Tags: appcode

I would love to have autocomplete in macros like for example,

```
#ifdef DEBUG
static void print_debug_info(object obj) {
...
}
#endif
```

Using a near-default configuration of AppCode, it doesn't appear this is enabled. Is there anyway to enable it?

Comment: I think macros is most difficult part for analysers. I would suggest you to create ticket on AppCode jetbrains tracker